# Gentoo Install php with postgresql and pdo with postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, gentoo

I've already installed `php` and now I want to install `postgresql` support in php.
I've added `postgres` and `pgsql` in my `/etc/make.conf` and `/etc/portage/package.use` But still php is being compiled with `--without-pdo-pgsql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're guessing the USE flags. The one you need to enable is `postgres`. Install and run ufed to see the full list of valid USE flags.

Comment: sorry I mistyped in question. I actually did `postgres` NOT `postgresql`

Comment: I've installed `ufed` and its showing `[-] postgres` I am very new to it. How to make it `[+]` ? I am pressing `+` button but not working